# Database Setup for Multilevel User Rights

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I'm looking to create a database for users with multi-level user rights and I don't know how to go about doing this. What I mean is that I want a manager of a business to be able to purchase my product; that person would be given Owner rights, but would also be able to grand additional users under that license--those people would be given Manager or User rights.  Each level (as well as my level: Admin, and my staff: SuperUser) would obviously have individual rights/privileges).

What I'm asking, more specifically, is how to set up the database.  For example, if my business is a corporate calendar/organizer, the Owner would set up departments, each with a Manager and many Users.  What's the best and most efficient way to structure the database?  Like, would each user (and each calendar entry) have to be associated with an ID that belongs to that specific Owner account?  I'm just a little lost as to what the best way to organize the database to keep everything together, as I will have multiple different Owners with their own company structure under them.

I want to use MySQL and PHP.

I tried to make this as logical as possible.  I think I'm making it too hard, but I am sure there is a standard that makes it easier....Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're describing a classic [Access-Control List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a little trouble understanding exactly what you're looking for. From what I've gathered, it seems you want a database that holds permissions, users, and departments. In this **very basic** example I've created 3 tables. (assuming one user can only belong to one department)

You could set a foreign key in the users table which links to the primary key in the permissions table. The departments table would have the foreign key of the user_id.

You could base all of the logic on what each permission can do with your queries and application side logic.

(I can't embed images due to not having 'enough rep')

[image]

Answer (score 0):

At the very least every product/object whatsoever needs a foreign_key in its table, as for example the user's id. This is necessary and sets the relation from the product/object with the user.

And then it depends on how complex you want your system to become. An easy way would be to just use boolean columns in the user table, like an admin, an editor column and so on, with only `true` and `false` as values. In your code you could then use `if` and `case` to check if a user is an admin and show him parts of your app or not. Like a delete link for example. But you could also restrict updating and deleting to people whose user has a `true` value in the sufficient column.

The more complex route would include other id-fields in the tables which set a relation of something to something else. Like say you want the user to be a seller or a buyer, then you would add seller_id and buyer_id columns to the products table and check if the ids correspond with the user_id. But not "the" user_id, but a different user_id which you saved when the user created the product listing for example. This way you could guarantee, that besides your staff the user who created this thing has rights to edit it, too, because of the product's user_id being the same as his user_id (current user) when he is logged in to your system.

You could do even more complex relations but then you'd have to create another table and save other ids in it which relate certain users with say other users. In this table you save let's say a maintainer_id and a maintained_id, both have values of certain user_ids but this way you could make a relation between objects one user could change, though they belong to others. Or if you're talking of customers so the mainter_id would be allowed to write messages to those people with maintained_id, like if someone is a seller and the others are potential buyers.

Comment: @JaredFarrish No, the foreign key corresponds to another primary key. In the  products table's user_id field would correspond with the primary key of the user's table. If there is no foreign key in a table, there is no relation.